# Separability of the space $C(C[0, 1], \mathbb{R})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let $E=C([0, 1])$ be the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$, equipped with the uniform norm. $C(E)$ stand for the continuous real-valued functions on $E$.

**I am wondering that if $C(E)$, equipped with some proper metric, is a complete and seperable?**

I am considering a metric on $C(E)$ which is similar to the Frechet distance: 
$$|F|_n \triangleq \sup_{|u| \leq n}|F(u)| \in [0, \infty]; $$
$$|F| \triangleq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{|F|_n}{1+|F|_n}, $$
where we set $\frac{|F|_n}{1+|F|_n}=1$ in case that $|F|_n=\infty$.

Equipped with this metric, I believe that $C(E)$ becomes a complete metric space. But traditional way of taking polynomials seems not working well for separability.

I am appreciate if you tell me the answer. If it does not work well with $C(E)$, answers to similar questions for $C_b(E)$ (bound continuous functions) or $C_L(E)$ (Lipchitz continuous functions) also help me alot.

Comment: Should the evaluation function $C(E) \times E \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous?

Comment: Also, I do not understand what $u_n$ is in the definition of $|F|_n$, did you mean just $u$?

Comment: I am sorry, it should be $u$. And what do you mean by evaluation function $C(E) \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Would it be desirable that the function $C(E) \times E \to \mathbb{R}$ which maps $(F,u) \mapsto F(u)$ is continuous? This is a likely requirement and it constraints the possible topologies. By the way, you're probably out of luck, this sort of thing won't even be metrizable.

Comment: If you adopt the norm I mentioned on $C(E)$, then the map $(F, u) \mapsto F(u)$ is continuous, I think.

Comment: To be precise, |F| is not a norm (it's bounded, it's not homogeneous,..). It defines a distance |F-G|, which makes C(E) a complete metric space, though not separable (it contains an uncountable discrete set) and not a topological vector space (it has uncountably many connected components). It's the topology of convergence on bounded sets of E, so the evaluation $(F,u)\mapsto F(u)$ is continuous. The connected component of 0 in this topology is the space of functions which are bounded on bounded sets of E, a Frechét space, topologized by your semi-norms $|\cdot|_n$

Comment: YES, you are right. It is a complete metric space but not separable under the metric defined by me. Thank you very much.